# How to inform GHC that a particular pattern match is impossible (ex: list will never be empty)?

Tags: haskell

I defined **selectionSort** function as below, sorting an empty list just results in an empty list and sorting a non-empty list is cons of minimum element and sorted version of rest of the list.

```
selectionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
selectionSort xs
  | null xs = []
  | otherwise = minElem : (selectionSort ys)
    where
      (minElem, ys) = minf xs
        where
          minf [x] = (x, [])
          minf (x:xs) = let (m ,ms) = minf xs in
            if x <= m then (x, xs)
            else (m, x:ms)
```

**minf** takes a non-empty list and returns a tuple of minimum value and rest of the list.

When i compile this function with -W flag, I get this warning

```
warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for `minf': Patterns not matched: []
    |
 24 |             minf [x] = (x, [])
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

It is straight forward that the function `minf` is never applied to an empty list, because those cases are caught in `null xs = []`. Is there any way to inform GHC that the particular case is impossible without using other types (`NonEmpty` list type) or `Maybe`s

Comment: I think in that case, you better alter the type and use an element together with the tail of the list.

Comment: https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=NonEmpty (But, this really isn't necessary here, why don't you just pattern-match right on the top level? Or use the standard [`minimum` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:minimum)?)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I think the OP wants to calculate the minimum as well as constructing a new list without that minimum in the same "sweep".

Comment: `minf [] = undefined` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, can't get minimum of elements, if there are no elements.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent. Better yet, `minf [] = error "selectionSort: cannot happen"`, which gives you a helpful error message when the thing that cannot possibly happen happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the idea is to "design" types in such way that the number of "impossible patterns" is very small (and prefereably zero).

As a *poor man solution*, you can rewrite the signature of the function from:

```
foo :: [a] -> b  -- [a] is a non-empty list
```

to:

```
foo :: a -> [a] -> b  -- head and tail as input
```

So in this context we can rewrite your function to:

```
selectionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
selectionSort [] = []
selectionSort (x:xs) = minElem : selectionSort ys
    where (minElem, ys) = minf x xs
          minf z [] = (z, [])
          minf z za@(z2:zs) = let (m, ms) = minf z2 zs in
              if z <= m then (z, za)
              else (m, z:ms)
```

So we here use the first parameter as the *head* of the list, and the second as the tail. Since the list contains at least one element, this means that the tail can be empty, and hence we can do pattern matching. As a result, we can still use the `-Wincomplete-patterns` flag to check if *all* patterns are covered and thus we still have some guarantees by the compiler.

In case you still have no means to design the types properly, you can for example add the pattern and raise a (validation) error:

```
minf [] = error "Impossible: minf only works with a non-empty list"
```